# Dataflow appears to be stuck. Works with DirectRunner, stuck with DataflowRunner

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have been trying to get the wordcount quickstart tutorial to work as per the instructions here (using Java SDK 2.2.0):
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven

When I run the example pipeline locally, I get the expected results. Great!

When I run the example pipeline on the Cloud Dataflow Service however, the service starts, but after an hour gives the following message:

```
(b87e004bcb71c8e1): Workflow failed. Causes: (b87e004bcb71c708): The Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to the Dataflow team at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow.
```

Can anyone help identify why the pipeline might be failing when run on Dataflow?

**What I've tried...**
**Options**

I have tried explicitly setting the pipeline options to account for anything that might be causing the two different results. Now I can run the following using the DirectRunner, and this produces the expected results:

```
mvn compile exec:java \
  -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.WordCount \
  -Dexec.args=" \
  --project=<my-project> \
  --stagingLocation=gs://<my-project>-dataflow/staging/ \
  --gcpTempLocation=gs://<my-project>-dataflow/temp/ \
  --inputFile=gs://<my-project>-dataflow/testinput.txt \
  --output=gs://<my-project>-dataflow/output \
  --region=europe-west1 \
  --zone=europe-west1-b \
  --network=<my-project>-internal-network-1 \
  --subnetwork=<my-project>-subnet-1 \
  --runner=DirectRunner"
```

(note: project specific names removed)

However, if I change just the runner option to DataflowRunner as follows:

```
mvn compile exec:java \
  -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.WordCount \
  -Dexec.args=" \
  --project=<my-project> \
  --stagingLocation=gs://<my-project>-dataflow/staging/ \
  --gcpTempLocation=gs://<my-project>-dataflow/temp/ \
  --inputFile=gs://<my-project>-dataflow/testinput.txt \
  --output=gs://<my-project>-dataflow/output \
  --region=europe-west1 \
  --zone=europe-west1-b \
  --network=<my-project>-internal-network-1 \
  --subnetwork=<my-project>-subnet-1 \
  --runner=DataflowRunner"
```

I expected to get the same results, but again got

```
    (xxxxxxxxxx): Workflow failed. Causes: (xxxxxxxxxx): The Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to the Dataflow team at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow.
```

**What I've tried...**
**Permissions**

After reading the other similar questions on Stack Overflow to get to this point, I am left thinking that this issue is somehow being caused by permissions.

I understand from
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions
that when running locally the dataflow service has access to the files and resources that my Cloud Platform account has access to.

I believe that when using the DataflowRunner, the service uses Dataflow Service Account and the Compute Engine Service Account.

I have tried giving "Project - Editor" roles to both of these service accounts to make sure that they can access the files and resources on the project, but I'm getting the same "...stuck..." message.

**What I've tried...**
**Firewall rules**

I have also set a firewall rule to allow the Compute Engine Service Account to access all instances on the network.

The latest job id is 2018-01-10_09_20_46-12253371190865296267

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct and complete job ID? I'm unable to find it in our systems. Also: do you see any suspicious logging in Stackdriver?

Comment: I've just double checked the job ID (2018-01-10_09_20_46-12253371190865296267) and it's correct. When I check the stackdriver logs, I don't see any records under Dataflow Step for that job ID.

Comment: @jkff are you able to see the job on your system now?

Comment: Hey Adam, I looked again and still could not find that job ID.  Could you post the message with the complete message codes corresponding to that error?  It may help us locate it.

Comment: Hi Charles, here's the full message:

(7b5c8e714b41bfbb): Workflow failed. Causes: (7b5c8e714b41b894): The Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to the Dataflow team at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow.